# How to block forEach loop while it is running to not be executed twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function called `sendMail` that get some email address and send a mail for this users.

This function is invoked by the click of the button in the user interface.

But if this function is called more than once, the email is sent more than once as well.

I'd like to block the function to not be executed again while it is already running. I mean, if the user invoked it, I'd like to block the button to prevent that the user click again and call this function again.

That's the route to send mail

```
routes.get('/sendMail', (req, res)=>{     
    db.find({ subscribed: true}, (err, result) => { 

        if(err){
            throw err;
       }else{                 
            result.forEach(function(subscriber, index){                                
                setTimeout(function() {
                    sendMail(subscriber);                    
                }, 3000*index) 

            });
            res.render('records.ejs', {root: '.'}); 
        }
    });
});
```

Once js is single thread and supose that I call `sendMail` twice, this function should be executed again only after the completion of the current execution?

I'm sorry if it's a newbie question. Any blogs post, tutorial etc are welcomed.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. Two functions cannot ever be running at the same time so your question seems inarticulate. Can you re-phrase to explain what actual problem you are encountering?

Comment: how the function is called more than once?

Comment: You are calling `sendMail` every `3000*index` milliseconds for each member of `result`. What behavior do you actually want?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I re-phrase my question. I hope it was clear.

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan I re-phrase the question to explain it. It's call by the click of the button. So the user can click it twice and call the function twice, for ex.

Comment: How you call '/sendMail' form front-end? add your front end code of button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have something like this

```
processingOjb = {};

routes.get('/sendMail', (req, res)=>{     
    db.find({ subscribed: true}, (err, result) => { 

        if(err){
            throw err;
       }else{                 
            result.forEach(function(subscriber, index){ 
                  if (!processingObj[subscriber.id]){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        sendMail(subscriber);  
                        delete processingObj[subscriber.id];
                    }, 3000*index) 
                  }
                  processingObj[subscriber.id] = true;     
                 }
            });
            res.render('records.ejs', {root: '.'}); 
        }
    });
});
```

Then it will not call for the same subscriber again until it is resolved. Just be aware to handle what happens in case of errors, otherwise you can end up with subscribers that will be never removed. You can also put there timestamp instead of true/false and only accept it if it exists and its not older than 10 minutes (to avoid some forever-blocking user behaviour).

This will not however work in case you have load balancer with multiple instances and you call the endpoint several times as differnt services can take it. In such case you would need i.e. Redis for such behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to block the button to prevent that the user click again and
>   call this function again.

One very simple approach that is often used is to simply disable the button after it's been clicked. Here's an example:

```js
// Get button reference and set up click handler
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Here's where you'd call your sendMail function
  // sendMail();
  console.log("send mail has been called");
  
  // Then disable the button:
  this.disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Another, more robust solution is to remove the event handler after it's been invoked. You'd still want the button to be disabled for a better UX.

```js
// Get button reference and set up click handler
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", handleButtonClick);

function handleButtonClick(){
  // Here's where you'd call your sendMail function
  // sendMail();
  console.log("send mail has been called");
  
  // Then remove the handler and disable the button
  this.removeEventListener("click", handleButtonClick);
  this.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Worth noting that this won't prevent another client from calling the endpoint. It's unclear whether the only one instance of the process should be allowed per user, or universally. The code doesn't appear to do anything user-specific, though. It might be better to solve this on the backend by moving the job into a scheduled background service. Calling the endpoint would simply place a new job into the queue to perform that task. The background service would ensure it didn't process a new request until it had finished processing the previous one

Comment: @ADyson Good points to make generally, but OP does state ***I'd like to block the button to prevent that the user click again and call this function again.***, so that's what the answer addresses.

Comment: I don't deny that, your answer is entirely legitimate. To be clear I'm not criticising the answer so much as pondering whether OP is really asking the right question, or has considered all the possibilities.

Comment: @ADyson Understood. ;)